# How to install Hammurapi in Linux to review Java source code

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to install the Hammurapi in my machine (Ubuntu 12.10), to do a static analysis in one of my java project. I've some guide lines in windows but not in Linux. Right now I'm installing it in Linux by using it. But it is bit hard since lot of changes are there in the commands as well. 
So, is there any body knows a place that can help me to get some guid lines to install Hammurapi in Linux.
I'm basically following
[www.hammurapi.biz](http://www.hammurapi.biz/hammurapi-biz/ef/xmenu/system/analysis.analysisactions/viewanalysisdocumentro/152/hammurapi+5+quick+start+guide.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained in the following URL : 
[run-a-static-analysis-on-java-project-using-hammurapi](http://nandirx.wordpress.com/2014/05/01/run-a-static-analysis-on-java-project-using-hammurapi/)